# JQuery Select Multiselect Options Based on Text Field

Tags: jquery, forms, select, text-parsing

I have a form with a multiselect field with several options, which looks like this:

```
<select id="testselect">
    <option value="Value A">Value A</option>
    <option value="Value B">Value B</option>
    <option value="Value C">Value C</option>
    ...
</select>
```

There's a related input field that, upon loading the form, receives comma-delimited text values from a query string (i.e. Value A, Value E). What I have been trying to do is have JQuery separate that text string by looking in between the commas and then matching the input values with the option values. If there is a value in the input field, then select the corresponding option by adding the attribute selected="selected".

Does anyone have any ideas? I didn't get very far into this before realizing that it's over my head. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var values = "Value A, Value E";
var $options = $("#testselect option");
$.each(values.split(","), function(){
    $options.filter("[value='"+this+"']").attr("selected", true);
});
```

Comment: Question: when you say var values = "Value A, Value E"; does this take into account the fact that the incoming query string will vary for each form? In other words, sometimes it'll be "Value A, Value C" or sometimes "Value B" etc.

Comment: @kramden88 - It is just an example, you can have anything in the `values` variable.

Comment: thank you for the clarification, I used var values = $("#textfield").val(); and it worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but here is one such.
http://jsfiddle.net/cBBkG/

Ive assumed that the "input" variable will contain whatever you get from the query string.